# Access Static C# Variable from Javascript in Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, variables, unity-game-engine, static

I am trying to access C# static variable from javascript in unity 3D. How do i achieve it? I wanna get the score for me to use it in the javascript.

**Score.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text txt;
    public static int score;
    public GameObject gameobj;

    void Start () {
        txt = gameobj.GetComponent<Text>();
        txt.text = "Score : " + score;
    }


    void Update () {
        txt = gameobj.GetComponent<Text> ();
        txt.text = "Score : " + score;
        score = score + 1;
    }
    int GetScore(){
        return score;
    }
}
```

**Collide.js**

```
#pragma strict

 function OnTriggerEnter(otherObj: Collider){

    var scoreScript : Score;
        scoreScript  = GetComponent("Score");
        int score = scoreScript.GetScore();

         if (otherObj.tag == "Wall"){ 
            Debug.Log(score);
             Application.LoadLevel(2);
         }
          else if (otherObj.tag == "End"){ 
             Application.LoadLevel(6);
         }

 }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not mix languages. Choose C# and Score.score.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the answer in points:

1. C# code is compiled before JS code
2. in general, JS code can access C# classes, the opposite is not possible.
3. However, you can affect the order of compilation by moving scripts into [special folders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html) which are compiled earlier. You could move your JS script to a folder called "Plugins" then it works.

You can also see it [**(1)**](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Script_compilation_28Advanced29.html) for more clarification while for detail guide of all steps available here [**(2)**](http://www.41post.com/1935/programming/unity3d-js-cs-or-cs-js-access)